# Hard code values into config.js assistance? CKEditor 3.2.1

Tags: php, javascript, sql, html

I am trying to hard code the bottom values into my configure.js file in ckeditor root.
My goal is to hard code all submitted text as black text color and a light blue background.
Values are below. How can I integrate these values into configure.js?

Thanks!

nano

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="td_big_non_bold" align="right"><b><u>Previous Entries:</b></u>  </td>
<td class="td_big_non_bold"><FONT COLOR="#0000FF">1:42:18: <p>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="background-color: rgb(0, 204, 255);">AC/DC</span></span></p>
```